# Не сохраняются картинки из ImageField

Tags: django, forms

Всем доброго дня

Есть модель с полем

```
Image = models.ImageField(max_length=100,verbose_name='Ваше изображение')
```

Есть форма:

```
class CreatePerson(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta(object):

        model = Profile
        fields =  ('email', 'City', 'Age', 'Image')
```

которая в качестве поля для Image генерирует классическое `forms.ImageField-поле`. Форма выводится на странице, все отлично. Но после заполнения полей на странице вывода формы и нажатия на submit, получаю вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пишет "Обязательное поле", хотя до нажатия картинка была выбрана и value input-a была заполнено (проверял через консоль хрома). У кого-нибудь было такое? В чем может быть проблема?

Попросили добавить код шаблона. Он простой и создан только для тестирования этой формы. на выходе код следующий:

```
<form method="post">...<p class="error_class">
    <label  for="id_Image">Изображение: <span class=upload_image>Выбрать</span> </label> <input type="file" name="Image" required id="id_Image" />
</p>

<input type="submit" value=Присоединиться>
```

Comment: Покажите код шаблона.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, докинул код в вопрос

Comment: Объявление тега `form` тоже покажите.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, показал и ваш намек понял: вы правы, я забыл указать enctype в атрибутах формы. С ним все заработало - можете оформить это как ответ, я отмечу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формы, использующиеся для загрузки файлов, должны иметь атрибут `enctype`:

```
<form action="..." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
</form>
```